# On making XMLHttpRequest to the server header("location:index.php") function not working?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am using Ajax in my project so in header.php i am using Javascript code for sending the XMLHttpRequest to the server. I am including this header.php file in every page of the website. 
Problem is here that in signin.php page i am using header function. That is not working due to the Ajax code i am using in the header. When i remove that code from the header.php. header function working fine.Please help me out.

header function i am using in signin.php:
header("location:index.php");

Ajax Code using in header.php :

```
<script>
function favourite(str)
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("like-div").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","add_to_favourites.php?"+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Just a small question: why did you place a jquery tag on this post.. and don't you use the built-in Ajax function in Jquery?

Comment: @MaxLangerak please guide me. If i am doing mistake in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the `Location` header does work, but it redirects the Ajax request that runs in the background instead of triggering a full URL change in the browser. Browsers handle this redirection of the Ajax request transparently, so what ends up happening is that the contents of `#like-div` are replaced by the full HTML code of *index.php*.

Obviously this is not the intended behavior in this case, so what we need to do is detect somehow that the redirect has happened during an Ajax request, and send back some JavaScript to manually set `document.location` in the browser.

A possible solution is using jQuery for placing the Ajax request (as it supports browser-independent execution of scripts in the response), and sending the JavaScript redirect code instead of a `Location` header when an XMLHttpRequest is detected:

**JavaScript**

```
$("#like-div").load("add_to_favourites.php?" + str);
/* see how much easier it is with jQuery? */
```

**header.php**

```
/* Function for Ajax-friendly redirects */
function redirect_with_ajax($url, $permanent = false)
{
  @ob_end_clean();
  if(isset($_SERVER["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"]) && strtolower($_SERVER["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"]) === "xmlhttprequest")
  {
    print('<script> location.href = ' . json_encode($url) . '; </script><div>You are being redirected <a href="' . htmlentities($url, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8") . '">here</a>.</div>');
  }
  else
  {
    header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . " " . 
      ($permanent ? "301 Moved Permanently" : "302 Found"));
    header("Location: " . $url);
  }
  exit;
}

/* Do the redirect */
redirect_with_ajax("index.php");
```

The code is untested and may contain errors. Use it with caution.

Comment: @solymosi..i agree with you but i want to know why header function not working when i am making ajax request on the server.

Comment: I added some additional explanation.